# Button placement on table footer view

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uikit

I have a table view wherein the number cells are not fixed and will keep on changing. I have to show two action buttons after my last cell in the table footer. How can I place them properly after my last cell? I know the pixel spacing between last cell and these buttons. Any code sample will be really helpful.

Comment: UITableView is part of Cocoa Touch, not Cocoa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always add two buttons to the final cell.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
  return [myCellDataArray count]+1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
  if (indexPath.row > [myCellDataArray count]) {
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Button Cell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
      UIButton *firstButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
      //customization
      UIButton *secondButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
      //customization

      [cell addSubView:firstButton];
      [cell addSubView:firstButton];
    }
} else {
  // normal stuff
}
```

If you want to customize existing buttons you need to set it's tag to something unique, i.e. `firstButton.tag = 100` and then set firstButton by `firstButton = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:100];`. Make sure you define `firstButton` so that it's in scope!

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ok. Got it. But what is the standard way of doing this. In this case let' say I have only two cells and in third cell I am putting these buttons then rest of my screen will be blank. Is it the right way of doing it?

Comment: If you look at some standard Apple apps, They sometimes have two or more buttons below a list and when that list is short it still stays right below the list. I suppose it may add regularity, and also the coding is easier :P. Just out of interest, what are the two buttons?

Comment: Its a cart related application. I have one button as "Add to cart" and other one is "Delete".

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried sticking them in a view and setting that as the footer view?

You need to give it the correct height before you add it; the width is automatically set to the width of the table. Either set it to a sensible width (e.g. 320) and use autoresizing or use a custom UIView subclass and implement -layoutSubviews.